# How do I convert an array of floats into an array of unique integers?

Tags: python-3.x

I have an array of floats, and I want to convert it into an array of integers such that the array of integers contains the same elements as np.arange(array_of_floats). I want the array of integers to be ordered to reflect the relative sizes of the elements in the array of floats.

For example, if the element with index 5 in the array of floats was the third smallest, the element in the array of integers with index 5 should be 2.

If the element with index 3 in the array of floats was the smallest, the element in the array of integers with index 3 should be 0.

To give some examples:

```
floats = [1.2, 3.4, 2.1, 0.4]
# I want to generate the following array:
integers = [1, 3, 2, 0]
```

Another example:

```
floats = [5.4, 2.3, 6.2, 1.2, 7.4, 3.2]
integers = [3, 1, 4, 0, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the list of floats and map the floats in the sorted list to their index in the original list:

```
floats = [1.2, 3.4, 2.1, 0.4]
integers = list(map(sorted(floats).index, floats))
print(integers)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 0]
```

Comment: Highly subjective solution

This result is an accidental coincidence based on the sample data. Test will fail if you remove one element other than the highest one. Similarly if you add a new element below 3 in to the sample data, then also the test will fail.

Comment: @gibies _Test will fail if you remove one element other than the highest one_ `floats = [3.4, 2.1, 0.4]` yields `[2, 1, 0]`, which is correct.